# How can i create admin for specific aws vpc

Tags: amazon-web-services

I searching for better manage my by create relevant role in my aws environment.
I have two environments decided by different vpc. One for dev and one for prod.
Does anyone familiar with some best practices on this subject?
For more specific question.
I searching for a way to create admin for specific vpc.
One of my vpc is for a team located on a different country do i want to create an admin for this vpc.

Comment: You can read about best practices for VPC and IAM in the excellent official AWS docs

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create an "admin" for a VPC. You can set up a policy for an IAM user/group to be able to only interact with that VPC, but this has to be done at setting permissions for various APIs that can potentially be used.
For an example see: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_IAM.html#subnet-ami-example-iam
You're interested in:

```
"StringEquals": {
  "ec2:Vpc": "arn:aws:ec2:region:account:vpc/vpc-1a2b3c4d"
}
```

You can go through all of the EC2 and VPC Apis and decide what you want to allow and what not to allow and setup a proper policy. Remember that probably you're probably going to need to access other resources (if using other AWS services) and you're going to have to properly update/refine the permissions each time.

The other way to go about it is to setup a different AWS account. You can setup consolidated billing so that you pay for both of them at the same time and you are sure that the other account is absolutely isolated from the prod one.